# Stop writing to a capture file after it reaches a specific size

Tags: networking, scripting, monitoring, interface

I'd like to monitor my network traffic of an specific interface to file.

Then I would like to stop the interface if the traffic counts over 60mb total.

Is there a possible way to do that?

Comment: Do you want to stop the capture or bring the interface down after those 60mb? Is that 1048576 * 60 bits of the ethernet frames on the wire?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`dumpcap`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html), the low-level traffic capture program of [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), can be instructed to stop capturing after certain conditions with the option `-a`. You can stop capturing after writing 60MB. This isn't the same thing as measuring traffic, since it depends on the file encoding, but it should be close enough for most purposes (and anyway the exact traffic depends at which protocol level you measure it — Ethernet, IP, TCP, application, …).

```
dumpcap -i eth0 -a filesize:61440 -w capture.dump
```

Comment: or just `dumpcap` (which `tshark` calls internally) if all you do is dumping the traffic in a file.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a *really* dirty method you could use with Perl and perl's `system` command. `tcpdump` will dump entire packets `-s 0` on interface wlan0 `-i wlan0` to file `tcpdump.pcap`. In my example, it'll stop all processes and shut down the interface after the file exceeds 1MB. Change to suit your needs. Run it with `sudo`. The `sleep` statement pauses the program to give `tcpdump` a chance to fire up.

I'm on Linux Mint, so program paths and interface names may be different on your system.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = 'tcpdump.pcap';
my $int = 'wlan0';
my $bytes = 1000000;

my $pid = open my $pipe, 
  "| /usr/sbin/tcpdump -n -i $int -s 0 -w $file &",
  or die $!;

sleep 3;

while (1){

    if (-s $file > $bytes){
        print "Killing PID $pid, tcpdump and disabling $int\n";
        system "kill -9 $pid; killall tcpdump";
        system "/sbin/ifconfig $int down";
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested your script. Do you see the fundamental problem that it has (A `if (-s $file > $bytes)` condition inside a `while (-s $file < $bytes)`). What does that really mean? And when do you think that `if` condition will hit.

Comment: Yes, I have tested it. It could use a bit of massaging for sure to catch cases where no data is injected before the `if` statement after `while` hits.

Comment: Fixed `while` and put `exit` in `if`. That should correct the issue you spotted.

Comment: And what if `tcpdump` takes more than 3 seconds to fire up. Will that sleep be still logical. Why to have `while(1)` & a `if` condition inside that. Why not do both in the `while` condition itself?

Comment: Because, it was a quick one-off, meant to help the OP. I didn't exactly have time to write a full blown, perfectly bugless application. It's a guide as to one way to do the work the OP asked. Perhaps you could edit my answer and fix it.

Comment: Would have appreciated if you did it yourself after the discussion we had in the comments. Was trying to improve & make your script look better. Anywayz would you like to incorporate Gilles idea into your script?. That command does most of it, just that you have to shut-down the interface after that.